# suppose we have a minimum m, how to prove that any element k in L is a multiple of m...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\forall$ a, b $\in$ $N^+$, let $L$ be a set, L = {n $\in$ $N^+$ : $\exists$ x,y $\in$ Z, n = ax+ by}, now suppose we have a minimum m, how to prove that any element k in L is a multiple of m...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $a+b \in L$.

**Hint 2** Consider the set $A= \{ n \in L | n \leq a+b \}$. Then $A$ is finite, thus has a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The set is restricted to the positive integers, and contains at least $a$ and $b$, so it must have a minimum element.

(Obviously, there is a little bit more to it than that, but that should be enough to give you a direction to go in.)